# Typescript compiler not solving Path Mapping modules

Tags: typescript, tsc

I would like to use ts-node with `.ts` files that use [path mapping](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/module-resolution.html) like `paths: { "@/*": ["src/*"] }`

and import like `import Sample from "@/sample"` instead of `import Sample from "../../src/sample"`

When when compiling `tsc index.js`, I got this:

> index.ts:1:18 - error TS2307: Cannot find module '@/sample.

**What is the Correct configuration for ts-node**

This is my tsconfig,json file:

```
{
  "compilerOptions": {
    "target": "es5",
    "module": "commonjs",
    "strict": true,
    "baseUrl": "./",
    "paths": { "@/*": ["src/*"] },
    "esModuleInterop": true
  }
}
```

and my sample project: https://github.com/daniel-dia/ts-path-mapping

Answer (score 0):

The problem is the invocation of the typescript compiler. If you are calling `tsc` with a specific import file, it [ignores a `tsconfig.json` in the same directory](http://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/tsconfig-json.html):

> When input files are specified on the command line, tsconfig.json
>   files are ignored.

Just change your build script to `"build": "tsc"` and add `"files": ["index.ts"]` to your `tsconfig.json`.